# Не понимаю, почему не работает vector?

Tags: c++, vector

Одно из действий в задаче, заполнить массив.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    std::vector<float>v;
    std::vector<float>::iterator it;    

    float m, n;
    std::cin >> m;

    for(float i = 0; i < m; ++i){
        std::cin >> n;
        v.at(i) = n;
    }

    for(it = v.begin(); it < v.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << *it;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не стоит исправлять код в вопросе на рабочи - после этого становится непонятно, что именно было не так.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Потому что по умолчанию вектор у вас пустой. И вам надо не присваивать значения [*несуществующим*] элементам, а добавлять их в вектор:

```
for(float i = 0; i < m; ++i){
    std::cin >> n;
    v.push_back(n);
}
```

Конечно, можно объявить вектор так:

```
float m, n;
std::cin >> m;
std::vector<float> v(m);
```

и тогда использовать присваивание.

И еще.Количество элементов массива у вас целое - а вы используете `float`.

Итератор не стоит объявлять в стиле C, вначале функции - ограничивайте область видимости переменных, т.е. пишите

```
for(std::vector<float>::iterator it = v.begin(); it < v.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << *it << "  ";
```

но еще лучше - чай, в 2019 году живем :) -

```
for(auto it = v.begin(); it < v.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << *it << "  ";
```

или даже

```
for(auto x: v)
    std::cout << x << "  ";
```

В общем, что-то вроде

```
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::vector;

int main()
{

    vector<float>v;

    size_t m;
    cin >> m;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    {
        float x;
        cin >> x;
        v.push_back(x);
    }

    for(auto x : v)
        cout << x << "  ";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Так если живём в 2019-м году, то может надо советовать `for (auto e : v)`?

Comment: @int3 Можно, но а если человеку надо разобраться с итераторами?..

Comment: Я не понимаю почему всем так полюбился `auto` как `var` в `c#`. Это же добавляет путаницы в код. Понимаю еще на темплейтах их использовать, но так...

Comment: А ещё можно считывать без лишней переменной.

Comment: @LLENN Просто `std::vector<float>::iterator` в 7 раз длиннее `auto`, и при этом в данном случае не вносит никакой повышенной ясности. Во втором случае - `for(auto x : v)` - я с вами вполне могу согласиться, тут просто привычка...

Comment: @Qwertiy Можно. И выводить без отдельного цикла тоже можно :) Весь вопрос в том, когда остановиться, и вопрос вкуса, что считать более эстетичным решением :)

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector<float>::iterator it;`
а у вас iterator**e**

Comment: Это первое, что в глаза бросилось.

Comment: Да, первая часть заработала. А вот итератор не функционирует.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы обращаться к элементам вектора, надо сразу создавать вектор желаемого размера.

https://ideone.com/FFUfU6

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  size_t n;
  std::cin >> n;
  std::vector <float> v(n);

  for (auto &x : v)
    std::cin >> x;

  for(auto x : v)
    std::cout << x << ' ';

  return 0;
}
```

PS: А ещё советую использовать `double`, а не `float`.